# open_basedir restriction in effect and subdomains

Tags: apache, yii

For security reasons I have put my `yii` folder below the html root, so my structure looks like this

```
/conf
/httpdocs
/httpsdocs
/yii
```

when running the site I get an error open_basedir restriction in effect that `yii.php` which is called by `index.php` out of `httpdocs` is not in the allowed path. Because this site is a subdomain do I edit the `vhosts.conf` of the main domain or of the subdomain?

What would the proper setting be to allow

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/yii
```

Path to be accessible?

---

EDIT

So my `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/vhost.conf` file looks like this now:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
php_admin_value open_basedir ".:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/yii"
FCGIWrapper /var/www/vhosts/example.com/bin/php-cgi .php
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've reconfigured and restarted the web server but I still get the error:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs/../yii/yii.php) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs:/tmp) 
in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs/index.php on line 26
```

Comment: did you look at: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir ?

Comment: for those still struggling here is an article that helped me resolve the issue: http://prattski.com/2008/09/13/plesk-open_basedir-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to specify the different modules or else simply editing the vhost file doens't have much of an effect. This is to turn off the open_basedir but you can edit the settings accordingly.

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/YOURDOMAIN.COM/subdomains/YOUSUBDOMAIN/httpdocs>
  <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_admin_value open_basedir none
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_admin_value open_basedir none
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

then

```
# /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=YOURDOMAIN.COM
# apachectl stop
# apachectl start
```

Full article can be found here: http://prattski.com/2008/09/13/plesk-open_basedir-fix/

Answer (score 1):

In the virtualhost:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir ".:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/httpdocs:/my/own/tmp:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/mysubdomain/yii"
```