# Yii basic url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, yii, url-routing

I am new to php, new to mvc, new to yii, and new to url-rewriting. So, I am sorry, if I am asking something very basic.

I have hide the index.php (from the htaccess method discussed in yii forums)

In my urlmanager, I have this,

```
'urlFormat'=>'path',
             'rules'=>array( 
             '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'view',
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
             '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>' 
              ),
             'showScriptName'=>false,
```

I have 3 files in view/site folder.

1. 'journey',
2. 'invite',
3. 'linkedin'

Now, my home page should redirect to 'journey' action (i.e. should open the 'site/journey.php')

So, I guess, this would be

```
'/' => 'site/journey'
```

It works too.

Now, I want 'journey/invite' should invoke the 'invite' action i.e. should open 'site/invite.php'

And, 'journey/linkedin' should invoke the 'linkedin' action i.e. 'site/linkedin.php'.

but,

```
'journey/invite' => 'site/invite',
'journey/linkedin' => 'site/linkedin'
```

is not working.

Also, can someone help me understand this,

```
<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>
```

i.e. what is controller in url and what does 'w+' mean ?

A reference to guide will help too.

**Edited after bool.dev's suggestion:**

Changed the code , as you said (I tried that earlier too, removing all default rules). 
Now my url manager is like,

```
    '/' => 'site/journey',
    'journey/invite' => 'site/invite',
    'journey/linkedin' => 'site/linkedin',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

But it throws an error

> "Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/xyz.com/../yii/framework/yii.php) is not within the allowed
>   path(s):
>   (/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php:/var/*****/tmp:/var/xyz.com)
>   in /var/xyz.com/journey.php on line 12 Warning:
>   require_once(/var/xyz.com/../yii/framework/yii.php): failed to open
>   stream: Operation not permitted in /var/xyz.com/journey.php on line 12
>   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/xyz.com/../yii/framework/yii.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php')
>   in /var/xyz.com/journey.php on line 12'

when I do `xyz.com/journey/invite`  or even `xyz.com/journey`

**Edit:**

It was a permission issue, @bool.dev's suggestion to put specific rules on top worked :)

Comment: ok what was happening when it wasn't working before you added my suggestions? i mean in what way was it not working? were you shown any errors?

Comment: I wasnt working either.

It works with usual syntax but throws error in url routing.

I can easily open `xyz.com/site/journey` or `xyz.com/site/invite`

but `xyz.com/journey` or `xyz.com/journey/invite` throws the error given above.

Comment: My htaccess file has this code to hide index.php file.

`Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php`

Comment: your htaccess looks fine, i think it's a problem of `open_basedir restriction`, so take a look at that. an initial google search resulted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328523/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-and-subdomains . sorry i don't know much about that. after you have solved that problem, i think things will work fine.

Comment: on some more google searching, i found more links to `open_basedir restriction` in yii, so you shouldn't have any problem in getting a solution.

Comment: also what's there in line 12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two:

```
'journey/invite' => 'site/invite',
'journey/linkedin' => 'site/linkedin'
```

are not working because the url is being matched by a previous rule:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

To prevent that from happening just make sure that rule is mentioned last, before any specific(i.e not matched by regular expressions) rewrites, so your rules can look somewhat like this :

```
'journey/invite' => 'site/invite',
'journey/linkedin' => 'site/linkedin',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

This : `\w+` means match any string with one or more occurrences of any “word” character (a-z 0-9 _) and `\d+` means match any string with one or more occurrences of any digits (0-9) . Check out [php regex](http://php-regex.blogspot.in/).

**Edit**

Hadn't read your question thoroughly before, the `controller` in the rule is simply a name for the matched expression, so you could have had `'<contr:\w+>/<act:\w+>'=>'<contr>/<act>'`.

**Edit2**

After reading your edited question with the rules array, *afaik* you could use `''=>'site/journey'` instead of `'/'=>'site/journey'`.

Comment: hope this helps..ask for clarifications if needed

Comment: Edited my question after your reply. Do check it.

Comment: i'm guessing my second edit could remove the open_basedir error, not sure. anyway, try solving the open_basedir error first, and then the suggestions should work.