# php read other php-file

Tags: php, file

I have one php page (index.php) with following contents:

```
<php
    include("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/somefunction.php")
    echo "hello world";
?>
```

Now I want to read the contents of index.php via another php-file (test.php)
The result I want to get is:

```
line 1: include("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/somefunction.php")
line 2: echo "hello world";
```

This is what I already tried, but it won't work:

```
$phppage="{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/index.php";
$handle = fopen($phppage, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        echo $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
else {
    // error opening the file.
    echo "An error occured";
}
```

It just echoes an empty string.

Problem solved :-)

Comment: Did you try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Comment: I eventually want to put the lines in an array.
I want my browser to show the php-code instead of hello world

Comment: is your page source is empty.???  check it please.

Comment: Place your php code within <pre> </pre> you will get it

Comment: Why isn't it visible?

Comment: i think it is because it contain php tags...

Comment: Thx, I removed them and it works!

Comment: @StievyDude ok i have posted a solution plz check that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code is working. The problem is it will not displayed on browser . Since it contain html special character like `<`

So either print The result with in a `<pre> </pre>` tag.

or use `htmlentities()`

```
echo htmlentities($line);
```

or remove `<?php ?>` from the file index.php

Comment: Thx, that works! Sorry I can't vote you up... Still new here. Can someone else vote him up plz?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the line numbers, which are not made by your code, you could do:

```
readfile('index.php');
```

or

```
echo file_get_contents('index.php');
```

Which will work as long as you work in the same directory. If you need line numbers:

```
$lines = explode("\n",file_get_contents('index.php'));

foreach ($lines as $key => $line) echo "line {$key+1}: $line\n";
```

And if you don't want to echo, well, that's obvious.

Comment: There is an error in your code (you forgot the close ) on the first line :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it won't work" - do you get any error messages?
Have you tried switching on error_reporting and display errors?

This is possibly security related - no permission to open the file.

Try using a relative path and double check that there are no [basedir restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328523/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-and-subdomains) in place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this...

```
show_source()
```

This function shows your PHP code in the browser..

URL: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_show_source.asp

Comment: That would be good, if I could put the lines of showsource in an array. I'll test it.

Comment: I can't get it in an array, so it's not useful to me. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
this is working try this 

read.php as 

<?php
$phppage=realpath("index.php");
$data = htmlentities(file_get_contents($phppage));
echo $data;

?>

index.php as

<?php

$absolute_path = realpath("somefunction.php");
include($absolute_path);
echo "hello world";
?>
```

Comment: I already tried something else, and that works, but this looks like a valiable alternative.